# Cannot access internet over WIFI in ubuntu 12.04 after I changed my SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I use internet through 2 Wi-Fi connections.
1 is home-wifi and 2nd is PICT-wifi .
There is at all no problem with PICT-wifi (which requires a PROXY).

But,some days ago ,I changed my home-wifi's SSID name to abcd-wifi. Then it would connect on manually configuring IP but doesn't provide internet (There was no problem in ISP).
Now, couple of days back I changed my wifi's name to home-wifi again, because I thought error with it's new SSID. 
  But , still , my laptop is getting connected to home-wifi and I can ping to the wifi-router but not to google(no proxy is required for this connection).
Following is the error I get when I ping google.com.

```
  ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Also, it is implied that I cannot access web pages from firefox nor chrome(Note: I removed the previous proxy setting , that I use for PICT-wifi).

Now , how do I connect to internet through home-wifi?

**[EDIT after finding a temporary solution]**
When I switch from PICT-wifi(uses proxy) to home-wifi(no proxy) then the file `/etc/resolve.conf` changes back to

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

then I have to manually edit this file to "nameserver 192.168.0.1" and then I can once again access net(this time for both PICT-wifi and home-wifi).
Why is /etc/resolve.conf is changing back to incorrect values on switching between the Wifi.
(note: it requires "nameserver 127.0.0.1" when on PICT-wifi).
How to avoid changing of /etc/resolve.conf file to "127.0.0.1" for home-wifi?

Ask me any other details if you need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`? Do you assign your IP (and gateway and DNS) manually or via DHCP (automatic)?

Comment: @erik , I have set my IP address manually , and requires no DNS.
I have got a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay , as @erik notified .I checked ip route and /etc/resolv.conf file

```
$ ip route
```

this is the output of IP route :-
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.105  metric 2 
192.168.108.0/24 dev vmnet1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.108.1 
192.168.110.0/24 dev vmnet8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.110.1

and

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf :-

nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

But,my nameserver should be 192.168.0.1 which is the Wi-Fi router's address.
So I **edited /etc/resolv.conf to**

```
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

This solved my problem. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You can mark your own question as the correct answer. Although I think you have to wait some time before you are able to mark it.